# How to apply multiple jQuery UI themes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-css-framework, jquery-ui-theme

**Does anyone have any techniques/tips/tricks to help me organize and implement multiple jQuery UI themes in one application?**

I have resulted to using `!important` as it seems to be the surest way to force style overrides - but this method is not very desirable.

Comment: Do you mean, switch style sheets completely or use bits and pieces at the same time from different sheets?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do. Ideally you only need one theme, at least that's the idea behind it.

Comment: @ dpmguise: I mean mix them aka bits n pieces.

Comment: @ daff:   I understand the idea and benefit to the entire CSS framework.  But I need more flexibility.  I'd like to be able to change, for example, the color of a button... ideally in a spin-off theme like ui-button-2 or something... i dunno.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, but it depends on what you mean.

Let's say you want element A to be styled with Theme X, and element B with Theme Y. jQuery Theme Roller has this feature built in. When you go to download a theme ([here](http://jqueryui.com/download)), click **Advanced Theme Settings** on the right. Here, you can set the "CSS Scope". This will let you apply the jQuery UI classes (i.e. `ui-corners-all`, etc.) from a specific theme. Here is the description they give for this option:

> This field allows you to specify a CSS
>   scope to limit your theme to a
>   particular portion of a page. This is
>   helpful when using multiple themes on
>   a page. If you don't provide a CSS
>   scope, your theme will apply to all UI
>   elements on a page.
>
> In most situations, you won't need to
>   specify a CSS scope. Please Note: If
>   you provide a CSS scope, you will not
>   get an example page included in your
>   download.

You can also change the **Theme Folder Name**:

> This field allows you to specify a
>   name for the theme folder in your
>   download. This is helpful if you plan
>   to use multiple themes on a page. It
>   defaults to "theme".

If, however, you want to create a brand new theme, borrowing bits and pieces from several themes, you have two options: edit the CSS and image files yourself (not recommended), or use the Theme Roller tool to create your own.

**How to Use:**

CSS Scope is just a CSS selector. Let's say that theme X should apply only to all elements with class `aClass`. In this case, your CSS Scope would be `.aClass`. So, if you want to add rounded corners from theme X to an element (assuming your CSS Scope has been set to `.aClass`), your HTML would like something like this:

```
<div class='ui-rounded-corners aClass'>
    Content    
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide an example of how to use the scope? that explanation is good, but I'm more of a monkey see monkey do kinda guy.

Comment: thank you for this wonderful answer.  been trying to figure this one out for a while!!

Answer (score 10):

you will have some issues if you apply this technique to ui widgets that overlay and are appended to the body - dialog, datepicker, autocomplete....

in the case of autocomplete, you can do the following to get a parent element with the scoped class - adding the scopped class to the UL of the autocomplete itself is not enough.

```
jQuery('.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        {....}
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
        jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').wrap('<span class="xxSCOPPEDCLASSxx"></span>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

searched for hours, and finally found the way to do it from the [FilamentGroup](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/using-multiple-jquery-ui-themes-on-a-single-page.html), complete with tutorial and working examples.