# How can I set different themes to multiple (jQuery) jTable on the same page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I need to place different jTable on the same page.

How can I set different theme for each table?

I've tried something like:

```
$('#TableContainer').jtable({
                    jqueryuiTheme: 'js/jtable/themes/metro/blue/jtable.min.css',
                    title: 'My table title',
                    actions: {
                       .......
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know jTable, but what's about to use a class in your table to address the general settings and an id for every table to style it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of jTable](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/GeneralOptions#genopt-jqueryuiTheme) It is pretty clear that they are using jquery-ui [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) for themes,

> jTable has it's own themes those can be used easily. But, you may want
>   to use color schema and styles of your jQueryUI as jTable's theme. So,
>   this option can be used to declare jTable to use jQueryUI's colors and
>   styles. To do it, set `jqueryuiTheme: true` in your jTable
>   initialization code

So, Then to the question how to use multiple themes in a single page.

jQuery UI provides a method for defining `CSS Scope` in the theme. Thus allowing you to define your own wrapper for theme, which in turn allows you to use multiple themes in a single page.

Please see this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250458/how-to-apply-multiple-jquery-ui-themes) for more details.

So after you download the theme with `CSS Scope` the theme file would look like,

- CSS Scope = table1
- theme= Sunny

jquery-ui.theme

```
/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
table1 .ui-widget {
    font-family: Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
table1 .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 1em;
}
table1 .ui-widget input,
table1 .ui-widget select,
table1 .ui-widget textarea,
table1 .ui-widget button {
    font-family: Segoe UI,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
..................
.....................
.....................
```

So, you can either manually add it in your theme or bundle it from jquery ui downloads.

And for jTable use it as,

```
<div class='table1'>//jTable here</div>
<div class='table1'>//jTable here</div>
<div class='table2'>//jTable here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand. If I bound to fetch my table through id (e.g.: `<div id="Table1Container"></div>`), do I need to wrap it like this `<div class='table1'><div id="Table1Container"></div></div>`? Furthermore, where I set theme path?

Comment: I also tried to add class on the same div `<div id="Table1Container" class="table1"></div>` but still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, the problem was the missing dot at beginning in theme scope: `CSS Scope = .table1`